# Measurement not correct in QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis, measurements, length

I have a SHP file of sub-areas of U.S. counties (roughly about the size of a Census tract) that I've reprojected into a 'true distance' projection (World Equidistant Cylindrical) in QGIS 1.8. However, when I measure the length of the sub-area border segments I get results that don't make sense (3 meters for instance). I've done this before in earlier versions of QGIS and my results seemed fine. Any idea what the problem could be? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

The CRS of your project is probably set on a geometric CRS like WGS. 
Try setting it to the same one you used for the shapefile.